# NestJS (node) - Validate request by generic type

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, oop, nestjs

I have two NestJS controllers

```
export class ParentController<T> {
    constructor(protected service: Service<T>) {}

    @Post()
    do(@Body() dto: ClassType<T>): Promise<T> {
        return this.service.do(dto);
    }
}
```

... and another controller, extends parent

```
@Controller('any')
export class AnyController extends ParentController<Entity> {
  constructor(protected service: Service) {
      super(service);
  }
}
```

As you see TypeORM Entity bound with this controller as T via generics. In "do(...)" method i used  ClassType as type for validation, but validation doesn't triggered at all without having any errors. As i understand it needs exactly class, not type to be defined as DTO.

My question is: How can i apply validation on method "do(...)" using just my Entity type (not using Entity itself in ParentController). I know generics don't exist at the JS runtime, and it's hard to make abstract controller without having this feature.

P.S. I need to do it without using *nestjsx/crud* component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in that way.
Actually, that was one of the reasons why I created `nestjsx/crud` package that uses `@Crud()` decorator where you pass entity type for validation.

Another option - you can create a mixin and pass an entity there.